# How do I get my Hyper terminal cursor prompt to be just " -> ~"?

Tags: azure, terminal, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyperterminal

I'm trying to achieve the following look with my terminal. Unfortunately neither running the command to install this verminal theme nor adding it to my plugins in .hyper.js config file seem to work so I'm trying to get there manually.

The image below is how my terminal currently looks and I've also pasted my hyper config file.

Right now my biggest hurdle is getting the prompt to be a simple "-> ~" like in the screenshot. How can I achieve this? As you can see in the screenshot of my terminal it is currently "anthony@DESKTOP-CE12BE8" followed by the path of the directory I'm in.

Any help is appreciated!

How I want it to look:
[image]

How it currently looks:
[image]

My config file:

```
module.exports = {
  config: {

    verminal: {
      fontFamily: '"Fira Code", "Ubuntu Mono",Menlo, "DejaVu Sans Mono", Consolas, "Lucida Console",monospace',
      fontSize: 14
    },

    // default font size in pixels for all tabs
    fontSize: 13,

    // font family with optional fallbacks
    //fontFamily: 'Menlo, "DejaVu Sans Mono", Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace',
    fontFamily: '"Fira Code", "Ubuntu Mono",Menlo, "DejaVu Sans Mono", Consolas, "Lucida Console",monospace',
    // terminal cursor background color and opacity (hex, rgb, hsl, hsv, hwb or cmyk)
    cursorColor: 'rgba(248,28,229,0.8)',

    // `BEAM` for |, `UNDERLINE` for _, `BLOCK` for █
    cursorShape: 'BLOCK',

    // color of the text
    foregroundColor: '#fff',

    // terminal background color
    backgroundColor: '#000',

    // border color (window, tabs)
    borderColor: '#333',

    // custom css to embed in the main window
    css: '',

    // custom css to embed in the terminal window
    termCSS: '',

    // set to `true` (without backticks) if you're using a Linux setup that doesn't show native menus
    // default: `false` on Linux, `true` on Windows (ignored on macOS)
    showHamburgerMenu: '',

    // set to `false` if you want to hide the minimize, maximize and close buttons
    // additionally, set to `'left'` if you want them on the left, like in Ubuntu
    // default: `true` on windows and Linux (ignored on macOS)
    showWindowControls: '',

    // custom padding (css format, i.e.: `top right bottom left`)
    padding: '12px 14px',

    // the full list. if you're going to provide the full color palette,
    // including the 6 x 6 color cubes and the grayscale map, just provide
    // an array here instead of a color map object
    colors: {
      black: '#000000',
      red: '#ff0000',
      green: '#33ff00',
      yellow: '#ffff00',
      blue: '#0066ff',
      magenta: '#cc00ff',
      cyan: '#00ffff',
      white: '#d0d0d0',
      lightBlack: '#808080',
      lightRed: '#ff0000',
      lightGreen: '#33ff00',
      lightYellow: '#ffff00',
      lightBlue: '#0066ff',
      lightMagenta: '#cc00ff',
      lightCyan: '#00ffff',
      lightWhite: '#ffffff'
    },

    // the shell to run when spawning a new session (i.e. /usr/local/bin/fish)
    // if left empty, your system's login shell will be used by default
    // make sure to use a full path if the binary name doesn't work
    // (e.g `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe` instad of just `bash.exe`)
    // if you're using powershell, make sure to remove the `--login` below
    shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe',

    // for setting shell arguments (i.e. for using interactive shellArgs: ['-i'])
    // by default ['--login'] will be used
    //shellArgs: ['--command=usr/bin/bash.exe', '-l', '-i'],
    shellArgs: ['-d', 'Ubuntu'],

    // for environment variables
    env: { TERM: 'cygwin'},

    // set to false for no bell
    bell: 'SOUND',

    // if true, selected text will automatically be copied to the clipboard
    copyOnSelect: false

    // if true, on right click selected text will be copied or pasted if no
    // selection is present (true by default on Windows)
    // quickEdit: true

    // URL to custom bell
    // bellSoundURL: 'http://example.com/bell.mp3',

    // for advanced config flags please refer to https://hyper.is/#cfg
  },

  // a list of plugins to fetch and install from npm
  // format: [@org/]project[#version]
  // examples:
  //   `hyperpower`
  //   `@company/project`
  //   `project#1.0.1`
  //plugins: ["hyper-material-theme"],
    plugins: ["verminal", "hyper-opacity"],

  // in development, you can create a directory under
  // `~/.hyper_plugins/local/` and include it here
  // to load it and avoid it being `npm install`ed
  localPlugins: []
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `bash`, you can try to put following in $HOME/.bashrc :

```
PS1=$' \U2192 \w '
```